# System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object while calling APex test class

Tags: apex

I am really trying to cover this small class for its code coverage but struggling to do that somehow. Can somebody please help me ?

```
public with sharing class MultiSelectComponentController {
    public SelectOption[] leftOptions { get; set; }
    public SelectOption[] rightOptions { get; set; }

    public void setOptions(SelectOption[] options, String value) {
        options.clear();
        String[] parts = value.split('&');
        for (Integer i=0; i<parts.size()/2; i++) {
            options.add(new SelectOption(EncodingUtil.urlDecode(parts[i*2], 'UTF-8'), 
              EncodingUtil.urlDecode(parts[(i*2)+1], 'UTF-8')));
        }
    }

    public String leftOptionsHidden { get; set {
           leftOptionsHidden = value;
           setOptions(leftOptions, value);
        }
    }

    public String rightOptionsHidden { get; set {
           rightOptionsHidden = value;
           setOptions(rightOptions, value);
        }
    }
}
```

The test class which I tried is :

```
@isTest
public class MultiSelectComponentControllerTest {

    static testMethod void testMultiSelectComponent(){
        Test.startTest();
        SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[2];
        options.add(new SelectOption('test', 'test'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('value', 'value'));

        MultiSelectComponentController controller = new MultiSelectComponentController();
        controller.rightOptionsHidden = 'Test';
        controller.leftOptionsHidden = 'New Test';
        controller.setOptions(options, 'Game&NewGame');

        System.assert(controller != null);

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

But its failing and giving me the error...

> System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object
>   Class.MultiSelectComponentController.setOptions: line 22, column 1
>   Class.MultiSelectComponentController.__sfdc_rightOptionsHidden: line 42, column 1
>   Class.MultiSelectComponentControllerTest.testMultiSelectComponent: line 11, column 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your test class, when the following line is executed

```
controller.rightOptionsHidden = 'Test';
```

It goes into the `set` method for `rightOptionsHidden` property. After executing the first line, the `setOptions` method gets called with `rightOptions` property and the value you are setting for `rightOptionsHidden` property. Now, the first line inside that method is

```
options.clear();
```

and since `rightOptions` and `leftOptions` lists are not initialized anywhere, it results in null pointer exception.

You can either add a constructor and initialize the lists or update your test method to initialize lists.

Here is the updated test class

```
@isTest
public class MultiSelectComponentControllerTest {

    static testMethod void testMultiSelectComponent(){
        Test.startTest();
        SelectOption[] options = new SelectOption[2];
        options.add(new SelectOption('test', 'test'));
        options.add(new SelectOption('value', 'value'));

        MultiSelectComponentController controller = new MultiSelectComponentController();
        controller.rightOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        controller.rightOptionsHidden = 'Test';
        controller.leftOptions = new List<SelectOption>();
        controller.leftOptionsHidden = 'New Test';
        controller.setOptions(options, 'Game&NewGame');

        System.assert(controller != null);

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize the lists in constructor. Currently they are null.

e.g.:

```
public MultiSelectComponentController (){
    leftOptions =new list<SelectOption>();
    rightOptions=new list<SelectOption>();
}
```